How to change apps color via ContentView() and @MainView using ZStack inside TabView()?
this is my ContentView()
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .view1
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Color(.green)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                VStack {
                    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                        View1(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                            .tabItem{Label("View-1", systemImage: "1.circle")}
                            .tag(Tab.view1)
                        
                        View2(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                            .tabItem{Label("View-2", systemImage: "2.circle")}
                            .tag(Tab.view2)
                    }
                    
                }
                //.padding()
                //.background(Color.pink.opacity(0.5))
                //.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)) // Apply rounded corners
            }
        }
    }
        
}


and this is my @main view
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

@main
struct NavigationTestApp: App {
    init(){
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orange
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack{
                Color(.green)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                ContentView()
                
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried putting ZStack in both @Main and ContentView(), together and separately but for the love of Xcode, it doesn't seem to be working - my navigation bar is working prim and proper tho

Note, NavigationView is deprecated, you should use NavigationStack.
Also, TabView should be the top most container, ie should not be inside the NavigationView -> NavigationStack.

A default TabView should always be at the top. It does not belong inside a NavigationView/Stack

That's quite a hacky way of going about it that may not be needed. Do you have a mockup of what you're trying to achieve? Or at least describe the desired outcome?
